# Subadderess transaction. How to receive?

Tags: sub-address

The problem is that i mistakenly used subaddress for mining pool, and they sent transaction(multiple outputs). Balance not showing on my wallet. What i can do with that?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, none of the current pool software supports subaddresses. Your best bet is to reach out to the pool operators and give them your standard address so they can update the pools database.

Comment: Transaction already done and pool operator can nothing do about that. But its not appearing on my wallet.

Comment: You need to contact the pool operator. They should be able to help. If they sent to a valid subaddress (a subaddress in your wallet), then it's not an issue with the pool and likely your wallet is either on the wrong chain or not fully synced. Ask them to confirm which address is was sent to and for the txid.